# How can I connect laptop with HDMI + VGA at the same time?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I have an old laptop in which the HDMI + VGA ports are next to each other. I want to use both, but there is no space between to use it: [image]

Is there any solution for this?

**Update:** Even with this, I do not have enough space:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look, hope this helps:

http://irisclasson.com/2012/06/16/re-cutting-an-old-vga-cable-to-fit-both-a-hdmi-and-vga-cable-on-my-laptop-asus-x53-x53sk-sx028v-for-two-external-monitors/

> So What I did was to use a thin blade and cut away the bits where the
>   screws are on the VGA cable,- it’s plastic only. Once I hit the metal
>   I carefully tore away the plastic and used a hammed to bend the metal.
>   ANd now both cable fit

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll use a hammer then to make it more thinner than what I have for my second picture of my post.

Comment: Of course you needed to reduce only the right side, which leaves the left screw for partial securing.

Comment: @AFH That makes sense, nice point!